# NSDateFormatter not working for single hard coded date

Tags: ios, iphone, nsdate, nsdateformatter, nsdatecomponents

I am using the following code to retrieve date and year from NSString. I am printing them in NSLog statements.

```
NSDate *dateC= [[[NSDate alloc] init] autorelease];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm"];
dateC = [dateFormat dateFromString:@"04/15/2009 00:00"];  // Only this date gives null date.
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MMM dd, yyyy"];
NSLog(@"date = %@",[dateFormat stringFromDate:dateC]);

NSCalendar* calendar = [NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar];
NSDateComponents* components = [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:dateC];
NSLog(@"year =%d",[components year]);
[dateFormat release];
```

This code works fine for every date except one that is mentioned in the code.
The output should be: 

date = Apr 15, 2009

year =2009


But the output is:

date = (null)

year =2001


Please help me why am I getting this weird behaviour?

 NOTE: I am using Xcode 4.6.2 and iOS 6.1

Comment: I tried your code It is working fine for hard coded date also. I got Log as: date = Apr 15, 2009 and year =2009

Comment: I tried it and it worked for me. Question, why the alloc/init/autorelase of dateC?

Comment: I am always getting this :-[__NSCFCalendar components:fromDate:]: date cannot be nil
I mean really, what do you think that operation is supposed to mean with a nil date?
An exception has been avoided for now.
A few of these errors are going to be reported with this complaint, then further violations will simply silently do whatever random thing results from the nil.

Comment: Works for me too. As an aside, your first line creates a date that's just overwritten late. The declaration is fine, but you don't need to set it to anything at this point.

Comment: Just to be sure, rather than using an autoupdating calendar, try this line instead, to be sure you are using a Gregorian Calendar `NSCalendar* calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];`

Comment: This line is not needed: `NSDate *dateC= [[[NSDate alloc] init] autorelease];` just do `NSDate *dateC = nil`

Comment: @Abizern. Did that, not working again. And my first log comes before that line. Its Null. So this should never be working for me. I guess i have to restart Xocde and Clean the project and run again.

Comment: @rckoenes. Did that, still no luck.

Comment: It works just fine on Xcode 5.0.1 iOS7: NSDate *dateC= [[NSDate alloc] init];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm"];
dateC = [dateFormat dateFromString:@"04/15/2009 00:00"];  // Only this date gives null date.
NSLog(@"date = %@",dateC);

Comment: @DavidH. I exactly ran your code but it is giving me date = (null). I think I have to check it on different Xcode and/or iOS versions.

Comment: @ShahidIqbal - here is an absolutely bare bones example with your code https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/585261/Tester.zip. It works fine on my system. See if it works with yours. It might help you narrow your problem down.

Comment: @Abizern I am not able to run that code. that might be you compiled it in Xcode 5 iOS 7 and i am using Xcode 4.6.2 and iOS 6.1 But I did copy  your code and ran in my project. Its still not working. Sorry for disturbing you guys, but no luck for me yet.

Comment: Almost for sure its your locale - try using a locale like this "[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"]" and/or the calendar [dateFormat setCalendar:[[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar]]

Comment: My guess is that that particular time does not exist in your locale/timezone, due to "summer time" transition or some such.

Comment: @DavidH Today I checked that code on another System with Xcode 4.6 and iOS 6.1 and it is again giving me null date. So I think this may be something with Xcode/iOS version. Can anybody else confirm me with same Xocde and iOS version please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try this exact code. Also note the section under `Fixed Formats` in the `Date Formatters Guide`, linked to in the NSDateFormatter class description.

```
// NSDateFormatter Class Description says:
// Note that although setting a format string (setDateFormat:) in principle specifies an
// exact format, in practice it may nevertheless also be overridden by a user’s
// preferences—see Data Formatting Guide for more details.
NSLocale *locale;

NSLocale *curLocale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
NSLocale *usaLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
if([curLocale.localeIdentifier isEqualToString:usaLocale.localeIdentifier]) {
    locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:usaLocale.localeIdentifier];
    NSLog(@"Created a new one");
} else {
    NSLog(@"USed the old one");
    locale = usaLocale;
}
assert(locale);

NSDate *dateC= [[NSDate alloc] init];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setLocale:locale];
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
assert(calendar);
[dateFormat setCalendar:calendar];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm"];

dateC = [dateFormat dateFromString:@"04/15/2009 00:00"];  // O
NSLog(@"DATE: %@", dateC);
```

Comment: Heyyyyy Dav... you did the magic. Its working now.. Real Thanks. Experience really matters.

Comment: @ShahidIqbal, so do you get the log message for a new locale or did it use the old one? There is no magic - I just read and re-read the documentation!

Comment: David. I put NSLog statement to check my current locale identifier and it showed me "en_US". So if statement got executed and it showed "Created a new one" message. But I figured out, the problem was not with the locale. The problem was, I did not set Calendar to NSDateFormatter setCalendar method. So just by adding [dateFormat setCalendar:[NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar]]; line in my code did the trick. But again thanks, I could manage to do so by looking at your code.

Comment: If you read the docs, it's possible for a user to change the date format on their device and break the fixed format conversion, thus the new locale. I don't know if that's just a OSX issue or could happen in ios too. It's probably safer to do it the way it is above in any case.

Answer (score 0):

If it is displaying a different hour you may need to set the default timezone (this happens only after ios7)

```
[dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"]];
```